# C++ program to simulate ls|wc|wc using pipes does not display output after running successfully

Tags: c++, linux, bash, pipe

The program executes, but the final output is not being displayed. I seem to be messing up the pipe lining of outputs.

Removed the checks for failure of execlp(),pipe(),fork() since they aren't contributing to the said problem.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "wait.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd[2],status,status2,fd1[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd1);
    char buf[12];
    switch(fork())
    {
        case 0:
                close(fd[0]);
                dup2(fd[1],1);
                close(fd[1]);
                execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
                exit(0);
                break;
        default:
                waitpid(-1,&status,0);
                close(fd[1]);
                close(fd1[0]);
                dup2(fd1[1],1);
                close(fd1[1]);
                dup2(fd[0],0);
                close(fd[0]);
                execlp("wc","wc",NULL);
    }

    switch(fork())
    {
        case 0:
        close(fd1[1]);
        dup2(fd1[0],0);
        close(fd1[0]);
        execlp("wc","wc",NULL); //this is not being redirected to STDOUT
        exit(0);
        break;
     default:
      waitforpid(-1,&status2,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec` family of functions does not spawn separate processes, they replaces the current process instead. As stated in [the man page for execlp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html), `execlp` returns control only in case of an error.

So, in case all `fork` and `execlp` calls succeed, your program cannot reach the third invocation of `execlp`, since one of `case`s in the first `switch` is always executed, and either of them replaces your process.

Meanwhile, I suggest you not to parse the `ls` output in real life problems, since file names in UNIX can contain whitespace characters, newlines, etc., that you probably cannot parse, there are other options such as the `find` command that can separate file names with `'\0'`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the second fork() won't be executed since the two process will mutate in the execlp instruction to the code of the programs 'ls' and 'wc' .
Check if it's that, maybe just changing the execlp instruccion in the default of the first switch to the second switch should be enough.

Comment: In that case it works. Could you please explain what does "two process mutate" mean?

Comment: Bascially the only time an `exec` function will return is if there is an error.  If the `exec` succeeds then the process that called it is replaced by the program specified in the call (the calling process 'mutates' to the specified program).  In your first `switch` both the child and parent after the fork call `exec` so neither process is running your program after that `switch` statement.

Comment: Exactly, when you call execlp , the code that the process will execute is the specified in the call, and the code below execlp instruction, as they said, will only be executed in case of error. In this case, the first process(name it Parent) will execute the fork, creating the process (name it Child1), and then in te execlp, Parent will start executing'wc' and child1 the 'ls', so the Parent won't execute the second fork() if the first execlp executes properly.